# What files to upload when submitting a debian package to Ubuntu Store

Tags: packaging, deb, application-submission, ubuntu-store

I'm going to submit my **debian package** to Ubuntu Store. When I submit my app there is a link "See What am I expected to upload?" that goes to http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/ that doesn't explain anything about files. Also I've found this link https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/my-apps-packages/. It's more usefull, but not clear enough for me. It says

> You need to provide us with the a Debian source package (.dsc,
>   diff.gz, orig.tar.gz files), bundled in an archive file (.tar.gz,
>   .zip, etc).

Let's say my package is called "foo". I've generated 5 files:

foo_1.0.0.orig.tar.gz (archive including source files),

foo_1.0.0-1.debian.tar.gz (archive with a debian folder only inside) and

foo_1.0.0-1.dsc,

foo_1.0.0-1_i386.build,

foo_1.0.0-1_i386.changes.

Also I have  a .deb file of course.

But which file exactly should I upload? Should I put foo_1.0.0-1.dsc and foo_1.0.0.orig.tar.gz in one .zip file? Should I put all that files into .zip?